# Regex matching group

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following pattern format of text:

- `[1/@DaysInMonth @FirstTitle] @SecondTitle`

The @DaysInMonth is gets on how many days are there based on the selected month, @FirstTitle and the @SecondTitle is alphanumeric.

I tried with the following:

```
[\1(?<DaysInMonth>\d\s+) (?<FirstTitle>[\w\s \]+)\] (?<SecondTitle>[\w\s \]+)$]
```

But it didn't seems to working. The matches character is 53 characters. [[Link]](https://regex101.com/r/7YPiUQ/1)

How can I solve this?

Edit after @baddger964 answer:

I want to use in my application like this:

```
private Regex _regex = null;

string value = "[1/30 Development In Progress] Development In Progress";

_regex = new Regex(@"\[\d+\/(?<DaysInMonth>\d+)\s(?<FirstTitle>[\w\s]+)\]\s(?<SecondTitle>[\w\s]+)").Match(value);

string value1 = _regex.Groups["DaysInMonth"].Value;
string value2 = _regex.Groups["FirstTitle"].Value;
string value3 = _regex.Groups["SecondTitle"].Value;
```

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: does something like this work: `\[\d+/(?<DaysInMonth>\d+)(?<FirstTitle>[^]]+)\](?<SecondTitle>.*?)$`

Comment: Hi Neal, thanks for answering, I have tried your solution, but it seems didn't work either. [Link] (https://regex101.com/r/7YPiUQ/3)

Comment: Glad you got an answer but for future reference don't use regex101.com to test for c# regular expressions. php, javascript, python regex are different and it can't test for c# regex. There is a good free program called Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) which you can test c# regex on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use this :

```
\[\d+\/(?<DaysInMonth>\d+)\s(?<FirstTitle>[\w\s]+)\]\s(?<SecondTitle>[\w\s]+)
```

for note :

`\1` =>  dont escape the "1" because `\1` match the same thing as the last defined match group.

`[` => ou have to escape this `\[` because with `[` you create a set of caracters

so your regex :

```
[\1(?<DaysInMonth>\d\s+) (?<FirstTitle>[\w\s \]+)\] (?<SecondTitle>[\w\s \]+)$]
```

says : i want match one caracter from this set of caracter  :

```
\1(?<DaysInMonth>\d\s+) (?<FirstTitle>[\w\s \]+)\] (?<SecondTitle>[\w\s \]+)$
```

Comment: Hi @baddger964. Thanks for answering, I have tried your regex pattern, it seems there is something not match. Here is the link: [Link] (https://regex101.com/r/7YPiUQ/2)

Comment: this regex work on v4 but not in v2 i don't know why

Comment: Thank you very much, will try that on the application. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
Here is an example of a normal regex if you interesse.

https://regex101.com/r/wLBj7Z/1

Comment: Hi @Lucas Carnevalli, sure it is works, but I want to match a several groups of characters (Named Capture Groups). As I will using it the named capture groups from server side (asp.net c#).